# Printing data of departments

Tags: java, algorithm, class

When I try to print out the data within departments, it prints only the memory of their address.

How can I print the departments and the data?

I want the `College` department to get all the parameters that are in the `Lecturer` department. That means that when I create a new `College` I want it to create a new `Lecturer` with all the parameters inside.

In `College` class, I added a method (`NewLecturer`) that adds an additional `Lecturer`. Is it written correctly?

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lecturer[] L1 = new Lecturer[] { new Lecturer("Dani", 2, "Banana", 1001) };

        College FirstCollege = new College("Hmpson", 2, L1);

        for (int i = 0; i < L1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(L1[i]);
        }

        System.out.print(L1);
        System.out.print(FirstCollege);
    }
}
```

First class:

```
public class Lecturer {
    public String nameOfLecturer = "";
    public int numOfTimesPenFalls = 0;
    public String favoriteIceCream = "";
    public int numAuto = 1000;

    //constructors, same name like class
    public Lecturer(String name, int TimesPenFalls, String IceCream, int num) {
        nameOfLecturer = name;
        numOfTimesPenFalls = TimesPenFalls;
        favoriteIceCream = IceCream;
        numAuto = num;
        int maxLecturer = 10;
    }

    //Copy constructor 
    public Lecturer(Lecturer other) {
        nameOfLecturer = other.nameOfLecturer;
        numOfTimesPenFalls = other.numOfTimesPenFalls;
        favoriteIceCream = other.favoriteIceCream;
        numAuto = other.numAuto;
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class College {
    public String CollegeName = "";
    public int numOfLecturers = 0;
    public Lecturer[] allLecturers;

    // constructors, same name like class
    public College(String name, int numLecturers, Lecturer[] dataBase) {
        CollegeName = name;
        numOfLecturers = numLecturers;
        allLecturers = dataBase;
        int maxLecturer = 10;
    }

    // getter, only private
    public String getCollegeName() {
        return CollegeName;
    }

    // setter, only private
    public void setCollegeName(String newcollegeName) {
        CollegeName = newcollegeName;
    }

    public boolean newLecturer(Lecturer addNewLecturer, int maxLecturer) {
        if (numOfLecturers < maxLecturer || numOfLecturers == maxLecturer) {
            numOfLecturers += 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sorry, Max Lecturer!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void sortLecturer(Lecturer[] arrAllLecturers) {
        int numOfTimesPenFalls = 0;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Wow, you need some Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.print(Object)`  will call the `toString()` method of the parameter `Object`.

The default `toString` method of `Object` gives you nothing interesting, so you will have to override `toString` to fit your needs, for example :

In class `Lecturer` :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
        return "Lecturer [nameOfLecturer=" + nameOfLecturer + ", numOfTimesPenFalls=" + numOfTimesPenFalls
                + ", favoriteIceCream=" + favoriteIceCream + ", numAuto=" + numAuto + "]";
}
```

In class `College` :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "College [CollegeName=" + CollegeName + ", numOfLecturers=" + numOfLecturers + ", allLecturers="
            + Arrays.toString(allLecturers) + "]";
}
```

Comment: i dont understand that line: Arrays.toString(allLecturers). becuase this is not Compiling.

Comment: @Liran : It is an utility method of class `Arrays`, that concatenates calls of the  toString() method of each object in the array , so that you can see quickly what it contains .

Answer (score 0):

create setter / getter and toString method for your Lecturer and College classes.